# How to optimize the performance of DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance, datagridview

I have a DataGridView control on my windows application form. This DataGridView is populated on the basis of a plain text file (specified by user at run time). Hence the number of columns and rows are calculated dynamically. Now the every thing works fine as expected the only issue is that my DataGridView took a lot of time to load data, is there any way to optimize the performance of DataGridView?

Hint: Normally the datagridview contians  1024 columns and almos 100 rows.

Following is the code for populating my DataGridView

```
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = nColumnCount;

for (int i = 0; i < CurrPageLines.Length; i++)
{
    string sCurrLinecontents = CurrPageLines[i];
    int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    for (int j = 0; j < /*nColumnCount*/sCurrLinecontents.Length; j++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[j].Value = sCurrLinecontents[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need 1024 columns? What user is going to read all that?

Comment: I think, you should divide this grid to a lot of grid, nobody read 1024 columns..

Comment: Load enough to make the grid look like data is loaded.
Continue loading in the background on another tread.
Then load the other data when the user looks for it.

Comment: @Jon your suggestion is good when there is lot of rows not significant when there a lots of columns, coz one row for all columns

Comment: @Erno
@Soner Gönül
there is only single character in each cell and there are both horizontal and vertical scroll bars aswell

Comment: Even a single character (assume 8 pixels for a character) 1024 * 8 + 1024 * margins and vertical lines = way too much to scroll. Feels like Excel...

Comment: Make sure you add `dgv.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;`. You can always reenable it afterwards.
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an article on MSDN on [how use the virtual mode of the datagridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171622.aspx). It even comes with [a nice walkthrough example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc.aspx). Although it seems to be more targeted towards lots of rows instead of lots of columns it might still be useful.

**Update**: If you are just experiencing delays when loading data you might be able to improve things by creating a `DataTable` or a `BindingList` from your textfile and then bind that to the view.

Comment: I upvoted since I was about to suggest the same thing. Create a List first then Bind it to the datagrid.