# Using Virtual Mode with DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which is typically populated with 40k-50k rows in the application.
If I have so many rows, then the performance of the `DataGridView` takes a hit during selection of different rows. 
What is the best method to optimize the performance of the `DataGridView`?
I read about using Virtual Mode, but I am not sure how to implement it.
Does turning `VirtualMode` to `true` take care of everything, or do we have to write our own handlers for when a row is needed to be shown?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Virtual Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171622.aspx) and this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc.aspx). Referenced from [How to optimize the performance of DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659204/how-to-optimize-the-performance-of-datagridview)